# Perl - No such file or directory exec error. File exists and is being called correctly (Windows)

Tags: windows, perl, runtime-error, exec, nosuchfileexception

I have the following [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) statement:

```
    $script_dir = 'C:\Users\mcnall\Documents\main_home\script';

    exec("$script_dir\\exec.pl", "$name", "$func_type", "$func_args");
```

When reaching this line, the error

```
Can't exec "C:\Users\mcnall\Documents\main_home\script\exec.pl": No such file or directory at C:\Users\mcnall\Documents\main_home\script\main.pl line 153.
```

The file *definitely* exists. When I copy and paste `C:\Users\mcnall\Documents\main_home\script\exec.pl` from the error above it runs the file as expected, it will just not run it through the script for some reason..

I *must* be doing something stupid, can someone please give me a tip as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try full path to perl.exe as a first argument.

Comment: @mpapec that did the job instantly and simply! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `mpapec` suggested in the comments, you need to specify `perl.exe` as your first argument:

```
exec("C:\\Perl\\bin\\perl.exe", "$script_dir\\exec.pl", ....... );
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I used the combination of your answer and mpapec's and its done the job. It seems the main problem was not including the perl argument which is strange because it worked in the past without it.
I think the only change was alterning the path from absolute to variable, is this a result of that?